# SQL Server project - how to publish stored procedure permissions

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures, permissions, publish

In my .NET WinForms application (in a Visual Studio solution), I have the tables and stored procedures in a SQL Server project within the solution so I can easily keep my schema under version control, and I can successfully use the 'Publish' feature to deploy schema changes to the development database.

I'm getting ready to deploy my application and have asked a user to trial the application on their PC against the development database prior to rolling out the new application and database schema changes to production company wide.

What I'm finding is that the application is throwing `SqlException`. I've managed to track this down to permissions on the new stored procedures (obviously, I don't have this issue as the owner of the stored procedures).

I can manually correct this by granting permissions on the stored procedure(s), as follows

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[<tablename(s)>] TO DatabaseUsers
```

...but what I'd ideally like to do is include this within the definition of the stored procedure(s) in the SQL Server project that's under version control.

I've tried adding the above statement to the end of the stored procedure definition (below) in the SQL Server project, the output from the deployment script seems to show the command being executed, however whilst it updates the stored procedure, it won't touch the permissions.

```
    -- Snipped 50 lines above for brevity
    OR              c.name LIKE @search
    OR              CAST(it.id AS VARCHAR) LIKE @search
    OR              ig.name LIKE @search
    ORDER BY        it.id
END

GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[search_items_allfields] TO DatabaseUsers
GO
```

I've also tried adding an additional `GO` before the `GRANT` statement in the above definition, but then I'm unable to use the publish script, as it refuses to run due to not being able to resolve the group 'DatabaseUsers' (without the GO, it's still unable to resolve it, but is happy enough to run it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the `GO` before the `GRANT` (so it's not part of the procedure), you need to add a script for the role to your project to resolve the reference:

```
CREATE ROLE DatabaseUsers;
GO
```

Of course, you'll need to add role members too. I suggest you manage role memberships separately rather than part of the SSDT project since those will vary by environment and many organizations have separate process for managing database access security.

Comment: Thanks for this, some further questions though, do I include the 'CREATE ROLE' statement as part of one (or many) of the Stored Procedure definitions, or do I include that statement elsewhere in the project? i.e. a generic SQL script?  Will this just resolve the reference, or will it also be executed?

Comment: Because we manage permissions via Active Directory, I'd ideally not have the `CREATE ROLE` statements executed and only have them resolve the reference so I can deploy the schema changes.

Comment: Include the role as a separate script with action build. I think this will create the role only if it doesn't exist. If your publish profile includes "drop objects in target that do not exist in source", make sure users, roles, and role memberships are excluded.

Comment: Thanks, I've been experimenting with this and have tried all the actions hoping to find a way of it resolving the reference without being executed. 'Build' is the only one that resolves the reference, but it won't run as the `CREATE` fails because it already exists. I'll mark this as the accepted answer, as I now have a way forward to find a work around for the remaining issue.

Comment: @Bryan, I don't know why SSDT would script generate a `CREATE ROLE` in the deployment script if it already exists in the target. I ran a quick test and the role was created initially but not after publishing again to the same db.

Comment: I've been able to get the my script to work the same way as yours, but I had to go into the advanced publish settings and on the ignore tab, check the option 'Exclude database roles'. This has a description of 'When true, Database Roles will be excluded from consideration during deployment. No Database Roles will be added, modified or dropped.'. This now gives me the exact behaviour that I want. Many thanks. - Apologies I missed the part about that in your earlier comment.

Comment: Glad you got it working as desired.